# Update a hidden input field with Typeahead.js and JSON key values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js

I have a working typeahead element on a page which fetches data from a remote url which returns a JSON string such as this `[{"id":"1","name":"Ben"},{"id":"2","name":"Josh"}]`.

I wish for a hidden field to be updated with the respective ID number. My current typeahead setup is as follows

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
name: 'typeahead',
remote: {
  url: 'backend/clients.php?query=%QUERY',
  filter: function(data) {
    var resultList = data.map(function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });
    return resultList;
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind handler for custom event **[`typeahead:select`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events)** which fired when a suggestion is selected. The event handler will be invoked with 2 arguments: the jQuery event object and the suggestion object that was selected. Based  on the selected value update the hidden field.

```
var resultList, d;
$('.typeahead').typeahead({    
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote: {
      url: 'backend/clients.php?query=%QUERY',
      filter: function(data) {
        d = data;
        resultList = data.map(function(item) {
          return item.name;
        });
        return resultList;
      }
    }    
}).on('typeahead:select', function(ev, suggestion) {
     $('#hidden-input').val(suggestion.id);
    // $('#hidden-input').val(d[resultList.indexOf(suggestion)].id);
});
```

Ref : https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events

Comment: I think this: $('#hidden-input').val(d[resultList.indexOf(suggestion)].id); can be replaced simpler with this: $('#hidden-input').val(suggestion.id);